# how can I toggle a boolean parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, boolean

I want to toggle a value called 'session' and then, update this value.

i've tried to do session=!session, but that didn't work.
session is a parameter inside a object, this object are displayed on my nosql database, i'm using the realtime database from firebase.

however session:true and session:false works

[image: session inside the update method]

obs: English isn't my first lenguage, so sorry if I used wrong words.

Comment: Please [do not post pictures of text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), put that text in your post (with appropriate markup). Having said that, I'm not sure I understand your need, can you (in your post) explain what data you have, and what you want your code to do, in order to get the data you need (where you show examples of both the data you have, and the data you need that to become)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to write a value to a path based on its existing value, you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).

Something like:

```
const userRef = ref(db, `/usuários/${fistKey}/session`);

runTransaction(userRef, (session) => {
  if (session) {
    return !session
  }
  return true; //  default value
});
```

Comment: oww mann you just saved my life, I 've tried everything. Before your comment I was in a infinite loop, trying to use onValue and the update function. runTransaction worked 100%

Comment: tanks so much to fix my question :D